# Including jar in project. And including Android Library project

Tags: java, android, jar, android-library

I want to include a jar library in my project, but the library is really large.

I am not using all of the classes from that library, so when I compile my project, will all the jar content will be put in compiled project or only files (classes, etc...) which I am using?

And same question about Android Library Project: If I include the Android Library Project in my project and I am not using all of lib resources, will the compiler put all of Lib Project resources in my project **or only resources which I have used**?

Comment: The problem is that you can't just include classes of the .jar that you use, because it will probably use some others class from the same .jar that you don't need. Android is not about only one class or one package, almost everything goes together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i apologize if i don't understand the question, but maybe what you're looking for is this:

[Selectively include dependencies in JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366974/selectively-include-dependencies-in-jar)

so here's the plugin

https://github.com/nuttycom/sbt-proguard-plugin

sbt proguard looks like it will cut down the unnecessary classes, so that your project will not be "heavy"

Comment: perfectly valid and applicable answer. too bad OP didn't have the decency to upvote either answers or select one

Comment: @kwikness thanks for the upvote! yeah, i think the OP probably doesn't know how to upvote or accept seeing that he only has limited reputation on S.O.

Answer (score 0):

Although you may not directly be using classes within the JAR, you could be indirectly using them. Therefore, it would probably be unsafe to remove these classes from the jar-- unless you're 100% sure they're not indirectly used by the classes you *are* using.

Comment: But I think, that compiler always know what classes are in use and what are not.